# Websockets on Okteto cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, okteto

Is there currently a way to serve websockets from an application deployed on Okteto cloud given the okteto-specific limitations around `Ingress`es and `Service`s ?

---

I've read that this would only be possible using a `Service` or `Ingress` of type `LoadBalancer`, so that is what I've tried.

But, according to the [Okteto docs](https://okteto.com/docs/cloud/build), `Service`s of type `LoadBalancer` (or `NodePort`) are managed. In practice they seem to get transformed automatically into a `ClusterIP Service`, + exposed to the internet on an automatic URL.

Do these handle only `HTTP` requests ? Or is there a way to make them handle other kinds of connections based on TCP or UDP (like websockets) ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a LoadBalancer to use WebSockets, they can be served from an Ingress with a ClusterIP as well (this is what Okteto Cloud uses for our endpoints). This setup supports HTTPS, WebSockets and even GRPC-based endpoints.

[This sample](https://github.com/okteto/node-websocket) shows you how to use WebSockets on a Node app deployed in Okteto Cloud, hope it helps! (it uses okteto-generated Kubernetes manifests, but you can also bring your own).

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it both with my current configs and with the example repo you pointed me to